# Terminate program when "exit" is typed instead of first input data

Tags: c, while-loop

I need my code to terminate when a word such as "exit" is typed into the first data input. I do not know that proper function or method to achieve this. My data is correct just need to terminate with a word command. Please any advice or tips with explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double xminA, xmaxA, yminA, ymaxA, xminB, xmaxB, yminB, ymaxB;
    double xminC, xmaxC, yminC, ymaxC;
    char end;
    while(1){
        printf("Rectangle A:");
        scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf", &xminA, &yminA, &xmaxA, &ymaxA);
        printf("Rectangle B:");
        scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf", &xminB, &yminB, &xmaxB, &ymaxB);

        if(xminA>xmaxB || xminB>xmaxA || yminA>ymaxB || yminB>ymaxA){
            printf("No overlapping area\n");

        }
        else if(xminA<=xmaxB || xminB<=xmaxA || yminA<=ymaxB || yminB<=ymaxA){
            xminC= fmax(xminA,xminB);
            xmaxC= fmin(xmaxA, xmaxB);
            yminC= fmax(yminA, yminB);
            ymaxC= fmin(ymaxA, ymaxB);
            printf("Overlap rectangle: (%lf,%lf) (%lf,%lf)\n", xminC, yminC, xmaxC, ymaxC);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Well, you'd have to allow for the user to input "exit", and it all starts by checking the return value of `scanf`

Comment: currently if the user inputs "exit" the program displays "no overlapping area" infinitely.

Comment: @KamiKaze: "*`fgets` is deprecated*":  What?! No. You mean `gets()` right?

Comment: @xing and alk. You are right, comment removed

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you need to acknowledge that all the input is text, then you can use `fgets()` to read a whole line of input, check whether it is `exit\n` and then if it's not proceed to convert the input into the numbers that you want, checking if they were successfully converted and taking action in case they weren't.

Example

```
char line[256];
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL)
    return -1; // Something bad happened
if (strcmp(line, "exit\n") == 0)
    return 0; // The user typed `exit'
if (sscanf(line, "%lf%lf%lf%lf &xminA, &yminA, &xmaxA, &ymaxA) == 4) {
    // Got the first rectangle, now do the same for the second
    // rectangle
}
```

So as you see, this should be a function so that you allow the user to type `exit` after the first rectangle input succeeds.

This could be further refined, to a level where you make your user very comfortable and happy.

Also, since you don't check the return value of `scanf()` your program is unable to tell whether the input was correct (*the expected 4 floating point numbers*) or if it failed, `scanf()` returns a value and you can understand it's meaning if you read some documentation.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't understand, are you able to add comments on my code? or if there is any other way.

Comment: There are many ways, this one is simple and easy. Why don't you understand? And what?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double t, xminA, xmaxA, yminA, ymaxA, xminB, xmaxB, yminB, ymaxB;
    double xminC, xmaxC, yminC, ymaxC;
while(1){
    printf("Rectangle A:");
    if (0 == scanf("%lf", &t)){ //<--this if() statement causes the function to terminate at a non-numeric
        printf("Program completed normally");
        break;
    }
    t=xminA;
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf",&yminA, &xmaxA, &ymaxA);
    printf("Rectangle B:");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf", &xminB, &yminB, &xmaxB, &ymaxB);

    if(xminA>xmaxB || xminB>xmaxA || yminA>ymaxB || yminB>ymaxA){
        printf("No overlapping area\n");

    }
    else if(xminA<=xmaxB || xminB<=xmaxA || yminA<=ymaxB || yminB<=ymaxA){
    xminC= fmax(xminA,xminB);
    xmaxC= fmin(xmaxA, xmaxB);
    yminC= fmax(yminA, yminB);
    ymaxC= fmin(ymaxA, ymaxB);
printf("Overlap rectangle: (%lf,%lf) (%lf,%lf)\n", xminC, yminC, xmaxC, ymaxC);
    }
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```